# Lit element object property value and placeholder is undefined

Tags: typescript, vite, lit

How can I solve it, without changing the value of the property, since I don't want to initialize it with an empty string

```
@customElement('mediator-element')
export class MediatorElement extends XmBaseElement {

  @property({ type: String }) value: string;
  @property({ type: String }) id!: string;
  @property({ type: String }) placeholder: string;
  
  protected render(): TemplateResult {
    return InputTemplate.bind(this)(this);
  }
}

export const InputTemplate = (attr: Input): TemplateResult => html
  <input
    id='${attr._uuid}'
    .?value='${attr.value}'
    .?placeholder='${attr.placeholder}'
  />
```

If I leave it, it handles with **.?** It doesn't show me anything in the placeholder. Empty sample

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

  <script type="module" src="mediator-element.js"></script>
  <title>Lit code sample</title>
</head>
<body>
  <mediator-element
      placeholder="Ingrese su correo"
    ></mediator-element>
</body>
</html>
```

But if I do it alone **.** It shows me an undefined in the placeholder

```
export const InputTemplate = (attr: Input): TemplateResult => html
  <input
    id='${attr._uuid}'
    .value='${attr.value}'
    .placeholder='${attr.placeholder}'
  />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `ifDefined` directive to sets the attribute if the value is defined and removes the attribute if the value is `undefined`.

```
export const InputTemplate = (attr: Input): TemplateResult => html`
  <input
    id='${ifDefined(attr._uuid)}'
    .value='${ifDefined(attr.value)}'
    .placeholder='${ifDefined(attr.placeholder)}'
  />
  `
```

**OR**

Use `nothing` over other falsy values as it provides a consistent behavior between various expression binding contexts

```
export const InputTemplate = (attr: any): TemplateResult => html`
  <input
    id=`${attr._uuid || nothing}`
    .value=`${attr.value || nothing}`
    .placeholder=`${attr.placeholder || nothing}`
  />
  `
```

[Reference](https://lit.dev/docs/api/templates/#nothing)

**[Example](https://lit.dev/playground/#project=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-IGh0bWxgXG4gIDxpbnB1dFxuICAgIGlkPScke2lmRGVmaW5lZChhdHRyLl91dWlkKX0nXG4gICAgLnZhbHVlPScke2lmRGVmaW5lZChhdHRyLnZhbHVlKX0nXG4gICAgLnBsYWNlaG9sZGVyPScke2lmRGVmaW5lZChhdHRyLnBsYWNlaG9sZGVyKX0nXG4gIC8-XG4gIGBcbiAifSx7Im5hbWUiOiJpbmRleC5odG1sIiwiY29udGVudCI6IjwhRE9DVFlQRSBodG1sPlxuPGhlYWQ-XG4gIDxzY3JpcHQgdHlwZT1cIm1vZHVsZVwiIHNyYz1cIi4vc2ltcGxlLWdyZWV0aW5nLmpzXCI-PC9zY3JpcHQ-XG48L2hlYWQ-XG48Ym9keT5cbiAgPHNpbXBsZS1ncmVldGluZyAgcGxhY2Vob2xkZXI9XCJJbmdyZXNlIHN1IGNvcnJlb1wiPjwvc2ltcGxlLWdyZWV0aW5nPlxuPC9ib2R5PlxuIn0seyJuYW1lIjoicGFja2FnZS5qc29uIiwiY29udGVudCI6IntcbiAgXCJkZXBlbmRlbmNpZXNcIjoge1xuICAgIFwibGl0XCI6IFwiXjIuMC4wXCIsXG4gICAgXCJAbGl0L3JlYWN0aXZlLWVsZW1lbnRcIjogXCJeMS4wLjBcIixcbiAgICBcImxpdC1lbGVtZW50XCI6IFwiXjMuMC4wXCIsXG4gICAgXCJsaXQtaHRtbFwiOiBcIl4yLjAuMFwiXG4gIH1cbn0iLCJoaWRkZW4iOnRydWV9XQ)**

Comment: You could also use `??`  ([the nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing)) if you only want to use the default if the value is null or undefined. 
`${attr._uuid ?? nothing}`